# Question concerning a notation in Vakil‘s notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Exercise 5.4.H. of Vakil‘s notes on algebraic geometry. We want to show that if $A$ is a UFD where $2$ is invertible, and $z^2-f$ is irreducible in $A[z]$, where $f\in A$ is squarefree, then $\operatorname{Spec}A[z]/(z^2-f)$ is normal. In the hint he sets $B=A[z]/(z^2-f)$ and I think we want to show that $B$ is integrally closed. For this, we assume there is $F(T)\in B(T)$ monic with a root $\alpha$ in $\operatorname{Quot}(B)\setminus\operatorname{Quot}(A)$.
First question: why do we assume $\alpha\notin\operatorname{Quot}(A)$, rather then $\alpha\notin B$?
Second Question: He goes on to say that „replacing $F(T)$ by $\bar{F}(T)F(T)$ we may assume $F(T)\in A[T]$.“ What does he mean with $\bar{F}(T)$?

If you have the feeling that I might be able to answer my first question by myself doing this exercise, please ignore it. However, thanks in advance for any clarification concerning the second question.

Comment: For an answer to the exercise, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408078/).

Comment: Thanks, I will come back to this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the notation, let $K,L$ be the fraction fields of $A,B$, respectively.

I agree that it is a mistake to take $\alpha \in L-K$ and it should say $\alpha \in L-B$. In fact, in practice one might even worry that some element in $K$ (not in $A$) becomes integral over $B$ (of course this can't happen here because $A$ is integrally closed). In reality it is not even necessary to assume $\alpha \in L-K$. If you drop that assumption, nothing changes about the proof. What the exercise shows is that if $\alpha$ is integral over $B$ then it was in $B$ in the first place. I guess that assumption makes the proof one by contradiction, but it becomes a direct proof if you drop it.

The polynomial $\bar F(T)$ is the polynomial obtained from $F(T)$ by replacing each of its coefficients by their conjugate in $L$. It's clear that
$$\overline{F(T)\bar F(T)} = \bar F(T) \bar{\bar{F}}(T) = \bar F(T) F(T)$$
which is to say that all of the coefficients of $\bar F(T) F(T)$ are fixed by Galois, hence in $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I might be really slow right now, but actually I don‘t get it 100%. So $B$ is a finite ring extension of A of rank 2, anf then L|K is Galois of rank 2 also? And since all coefficients of $\bar{F}(T)F(T)$ are fixed by Galois, they lie in $K\cap B=A$?

Comment: Yup since $f$ is square free the polynomial is irreducible, which means that the extension is degree 2. Separability is no problem since the characteristic isn’t 2 (as 2 is invertible). And you are exactly right, the coefficients of $F\bar F$ are a priori just in K but clearly also in B which means they are in $K\cap B=A$.